What would be a good or standard methodology for generalizing the “36 questions”?
There are these 36 questions from a study which are designed to socially bond people by being increasingly “personal”.
I am interested in knowing a standard methodology for trying to generalize those specific 36 questions, to focus on general underlying factors which are hypothesized to explain why they specifically might be better than other arbitrary questions.
For example, it could use natural language processing and statistics to figure out what domains, categories or topics regarding the self are for some reason more important to forming social bonds than others (i.e., family relations, religion, life goals, social values, interests).
So what is a concrete and specific example of generalizing those specific 36 questions into an underlying model or ontology of what facets of human social psychology are actually relevant to the 36 questions, what specific effect each one has, what explains why they are apparently socially bonding questions?
